# vscode only comments in html and doesn't recognize internal js or css

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

when I press command+/ regardless of the position where i press it in the code. As long as the file is an html file the comment is an html comment. Am I missing some extension?

I tried pressing command+/ in css elements and js code inside of an html file in vscode. I tried enabling emmet and it worked with internal css but not with internal javascript but also instead of one line of comment it comments a big chunk/section of code...

Comment: Hi ! Please [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Which extentions do you have installed? Instead of typing command+/ you can also write /*, same number of key strokes.